# unable to start the mysql in xampp, windows 8.1

Tags: xampp

**it shows an error like below :**
*There may be an error return code 1123, the operation was cancelled by the user.

Thanks in Advance*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe MySQL is set to only start manually. Mine is.

I have to open a command prompt as admin and can use this command to start MySQL, Change it to suit your path to MySQL.

-> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\mysql\bin
-> mysqld